# How to pause HTML & JavaScript document load until AJAX query results are in?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, asynchronous, callback

I have been using an AJAX query in my JavaScript code, and want my HTML & JavaScript code to pause loading until the results of the query are in. Is this possible? I believe async functions continue executing your code but make it possible to 'callback' to the function once it has completed a step. In my case I just want everything to stop, so nothng happening asynchronously.

For an example, please see my code below.

```
      function ajaxQuerySpotify(stringIncrementalAmount) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks?limit=50&offset=' + stringIncrementalAmount,
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            success: function(response) {

              for (i = 0; i < response['items'].length; i++) {
                songIDs.push(response['items'][i]['track']['id']);
                songNames.push(response['items'][i]['track']['album']['artists'][0]['name']);
                SongArtists.push(response['items'][i]['track']['name']);
              }

              requestCount += 1;
              incrementalRequest = requestCount * incrementalAmount;
              stringIncrementalAmount = String(incrementalRequest);
              // console.log(stringIncrementalAmount);

              // SET BACK TO 1000 ONCE COMPLETED TESTING
              if (incrementalRequest >= 999) {
                return false;
              }

              // Keeps requerying until nothing can be found anymore
              ajaxQuerySpotify(stringIncrementalAmount);
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: you can't really pause it. I would show a loading screen, then hide it once you have the data you need to render the page.

Comment: Yeah, all you can really do is show some sort of loader that blocks user input somehow until the AJAX call returns.

Comment: @dandavis But the HTML will already have been rendered? Reason I'm asking is because currently the array that have items pushed to them in the attached code (songIDs, songNames) receive the pushed items too late when a different function has finished executing in parallel. I need those items pushed and have the rest of the code continue once done. Really not a way to do this?